# UIActivityIndicatorView dialog over view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app I'm using a custom UIActivityIndicator view ([this](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView)) and it works great.
I have an UITableView and I want the indicator over the tableview on loading data. To solve the problem I have created an empty view with a background above all and when I need to start indicator's animation I simply hide tableview and show the empty view + the indicator.

The result is this:

[image: Image 1]

I saw somewhere that I can use instead something like this:

[image: Image 2]

How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the dim background?

Comment: Wouldn't `NVActivityIndicatorViewable` work for you?

Comment: @SonLe yes I think it is what I'm searching

Comment: @srvv I really don't know, can you explain better please?

Comment: add this protocol conformance to your view controller and you will get `startActivityAnimating` & `stopActivityAnimating` methods which you could use.

Comment: @Jigen set the color of the empty view to black, and set it's alpha to 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a translucent Black view over the Table View and put the custom activity indicator code as a subview in the Black view.

```
let aBlackView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
aBlackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
aBlackView.alpha = 0.75 // Change the alpha depending on how much transparency you require

let aMainWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window
aMainWindow!!.addSubview(aBlackView)

/* Enter you code for NVActivityIndicatorViewable here */

aBlackView.addSubview(/* NVActivityIndicatorViewable */)
```

Once you are done with your request, you can remove the Black view by calling this code:

```
aBlackView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a activity showing screen . I used in every where in my project.

//ProgressBarNotification.swift

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit

class ProgressBarNotification {

internal static var strLabel = UILabel()
internal static var messageFrame = UIView()
internal static var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()    

internal static func progressBarDisplayer(msg:String,indicator:Bool ){


    let view1 = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.rootViewController?.view

    view1?.userInteractionEnabled = false

    strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
    strLabel.text = msg
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    messageFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view1!.frame.midX - 90, y: view1!.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))
    messageFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    messageFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
    if indicator {
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        messageFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
    messageFrame.addSubview(strLabel)
    view1!.addSubview(messageFrame)


}

internal static func removeProgressBar() {

    let view1 = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.rootViewController?.view

    _ = view1?.subviews.filter({ (view) -> Bool in
        if view == ProgressBarNotification.messageFrame {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        return false
    })

    ProgressBarNotification.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()

    view1?.userInteractionEnabled = true

}

  deinit{

  }
}
```

Usage

```
    //To start Loader

    ProgressBarNotification.progressBarDisplayer("Loading", indicator: true)

   //Stop 

    ProgressBarNotification.removeProgressBar()
```